# contour integral z/conjugate(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to calculate:
$$\int_C \frac{z}{\bar{z}}dz$$ where C is [the upper semicircles of the circles centred in (0,0) of radii 1,2 joined at their intersections with the real axis by the real segments  [−2,−1],[1,2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slmkb.jpg)  (counter clockwise)

$\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of z.

This is a basic problem from my mathbook. Their result is 0. However my calculation disagrees.
I disected the contour into two line segments and two half circles. So I have four integrals:

1) $$\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{x}{x}dx=1$$
2) $$\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{-it}ie^{it}}dt=\frac{2}{3}$$
3) $$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x}{x}dx=1$$
4) $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{-it}ie^{it}}dt=-\frac{4}{3}$$

When I add them up I get 4/3 which is not correct according to the book.The results in the book are usually correct so I want to ask if I do it right. (I can't use the Cauchy theorem since $\bar{z}$ is not holomorphic in a single point.)

Comment: If the contour is what your drawing shows I can't see any mistake here. Yet the wording troubles me a little: what does "the **circumference** of *upper annulus* ...." mean?? If it is a circumference then it is *not*, in my opinion, what you drew.

Comment: Well I didn't know how to describe it in english. It's more or less direct translation of what's in the book. The picture should be correct. Maybe "the boundary of upper half-annulus" would be a better definition? Thanks for opinion there is probably a mistake in the book.

Comment: circumference implies we have a circle, however its center is 0, so we can't only consider the upper half plane

Comment: I'd describe it succintly as "the upper semicircles of the canonical circles of radius $\;1,\,2\;$ joined at their intersections with the real axis by the real segments $\;[-2,-1]\,,\,\,[1,2]\;$" , or something like that. But if you're sure your drawing describes accurately what the question means (in your language), then I'd say there's a mistake in the book's answer. (which book is that, by the way?)

Comment: @AlvinLepik Singularities, for a problem like this, seem to be irrelevant as the given function isn't analytic *anywhere* .

Comment: Your integral, as written, makes no sense since there is no term like $dz$, $d\bar z$, $|dz|$, or similar. Look at your examples 1)–4); they all have such a term.